# Adafruit nRF52 feather board [SOLVED]

Tags: bluetooth

I am working on a project (the scenario is depicted in the attachment) involving Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). As a master (central device) I am using the Adafruit nRF52 feather board (https://learn.adafruit.com/bluefruit-nrf52-feather-learning-guide/introduction) and as slaves (peripheral devices) a pair of Adafruit nRF8001 modules (https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/pinouts?view=all#introduction). Moreover, I have to wire the nRF52 up with an Arduino Uno rev3.

I am trying to set up the very initial communication between central and peripheral devices, but if I even try to upload the blinky sketch into the nRF52 board the compiling phase returns to me the following error:

> exec: "nrfutil": executable file not found in $PATH

Does anyone have an idea what it means? I googled a lot but I am not able to figure it out on this problem.

Thanks in advance to anyone would be able to help me!

Filippo

[image]

**[EDIT]** Solved: just need to install the nfrutil first, as written in https://learn.adafruit.com/bluefruit-nrf52-feather-learning-guide/arduino-bsp-setup#nrfutil-os-x-and-linux-only

Comment: mind sharing your code on github?

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you solved the problem in an answer (or edit monkSinha's answer)? That adafruit website may not exist at the same address in the future, so it would help to give a complete answer to future readers of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Step 2 solves this problem:

https://learn.adafruit.com/bluefruit-nrf52-feather-learning-guide/arduino-bsp-setup

Also, read up about how to add something to Path Variable on Windows.